# How to make the ball animate like its rolling And also the kicker how to animate the soccer player and how to sync them so it looks like he is kicking

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

THE PROGRAM HAS 3 FORMS
FORM 1 CODE

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Form2.Show()
        Form2.Location = New Point(485, 100)
        Form2.Width = 400
        Form2.Height = 300

        Form3.Show()
        Form3.Location = New Point(860, 100)
        Form3.Width = 400
        Form3.Height = 300

        Me.Location = New Point(100, 100)
        Me.Width = 400
        Me.Height = 300

        Me.Location = New Point(100, 100)
        Me.Width = 400
        Me.Height = 300
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        OS1.Left = OS1.Left + 3
        Form2.OS2.Visible = False
        Form3.OS3.Visible = False
        If OS1.Left >= 350 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            OS1.Visible = False
            Form2.OS2.Visible = True
            Form2.Timer1.Start()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

FORM 2 CODE

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        OS2.Left = OS2.Left + 3
        If OS2.Left >= 350 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            OS2.Visible = False
            Form3.OS3.Visible = True
            Form3.Timer1.Start()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

FORM 3 CODE

```
Public Class Form3

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        OS3.Left = OS3.Left + 3
        If OS3.Left >= 200 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            Timer2.Start()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNpoG.png)

I also have a video link on how it currently works link:
https://youtu.be/JgBN4Uxdm_w
I just want the sprites to animate I have 12 pictures of the soccer ball and 5 pictures for the player in my resources I just want them to animate.

Comment: Assuming OS1, OS2 & OS3 are picture boxes, wouldn't it simply be a case of changing the image as required?  That seems simple enough so wonder if there is more to this question.  That said though, this does seem like a horribly inefficient way to animate but don't have any other suggestions other than gifs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is my code for form 1
Public Class Form1

```
Public mv As Integer = 1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form2.Show()
    Form2.Location = New Point(485, 100)
    Form2.Width = 400
    Form2.Height = 300
    Form3.Show()
    Form3.Location = New Point(860, 100)
    Form3.Width = 400
    Form3.Height = 300

    Me.Location = New Point(100, 100)
    Me.Width = 400
    Me.Height = 300

    Me.Location = New Point(100, 100)
    Me.Width = 400
    Me.Height = 300
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    OS1.Left = OS1.Left + 3
    Form2.OS2.Visible = False
    Form3.OS3.Visible = False
    If OS1.Left >= 350 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        OS1.Visible = False
        Form2.mv = Me.mv
        Form2.OS2.Visible = True
        Form2.Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub animate()
    If mv = 1 Then
        OS1.Image = Image.FromFile("football1.png")
        mv = 2
    ElseIf mv = 2 Then
        OS1.Image = Image.FromFile("football2.png")
        mv = 3
    ElseIf mv = 3 Then
        OS1.Image = Image.FromFile("football3.png")
        mv = 4
    ElseIf mv = 4 Then
        OS1.Image = Image.FromFile("football4.png")
        mv = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Form 2 code
Public Class Form2

```
Public mv As Integer = 1
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    OS2.Left = OS2.Left + 3
    OS2.Visible = True
    Form3.OS3.Visible = False
    If OS2.Left >= 350 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        OS2.Visible = False
        Form3.mv = Me.mv
        Form3.OS3.Visible = True
        Form3.Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub animate()
    If mv = 1 Then
        OS2.Image = Image.FromFile("football1.png")
        mv = 2
    ElseIf mv = 2 Then
        OS2.Image = Image.FromFile("football2.png")
        mv = 3
    ElseIf mv = 3 Then
        OS2.Image = Image.FromFile("football3.png")
        mv = 4
    ElseIf mv = 4 Then
        OS2.Image = Image.FromFile("football4.png")
        mv = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Form 3 code
Public Class Form3

```
Public mv As Integer = 1
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    OS3.Left = OS3.Left + 3
    OS3.Visible = True
    If OS3.Left >= 350 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        OS3.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub animate()
    If mv = 1 Then
        OS3.Image = Image.FromFile("football1.png")
        mv = 2
    ElseIf mv = 2 Then
        OS3.Image = Image.FromFile("football2.png")
        mv = 3
    ElseIf mv = 3 Then
        OS3.Image = Image.FromFile("football3.png")
        mv = 4
    ElseIf mv = 4 Then
        OS3.Image = Image.FromFile("football4.png")
        mv = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

And the error message:

FileNotfoundException was unhandled
C:\Users\63921\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ptptpttptptptpptptpt\ptptpttptptptptpptptpt\bin\Debugsoccerball1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsSyA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTJtk.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can set animation functions for OS1, OS2, OS3 respectively.
Then pass a parameter directly in the form to make the animation coherent.
But using pictures to animate is very inefficient.
Here's a rather crude approach based on your code implementation.

Form1

```
    Public Dim mv As Integer = 1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Form2.Show()
    Form2.Location = New Point(485, 100)
    Form2.Width = 400
    Form2.Height = 300
    Form3.Show()
    Form3.Location = New Point(860, 100)
    Form3.Width = 400
    Form3.Height = 300

    Me.Location = New Point(100, 100)
    Me.Width = 400
    Me.Height = 300

    Me.Location = New Point(100, 100)
    Me.Width = 400
    Me.Height = 300
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    OS1.Left = OS1.Left + 3
    Form2.OS2.Visible = False
    Form3.OS3.Visible = False
    If OS1.Left >= 350 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        OS1.Visible = False
        Form2.mv = Me.mv
        Form2.OS2.Visible = True
        Form2.Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub animate()
    If mv = 1 Then
        OS1.Image = Image.FromFile("football1")
        mv = 2
    ElseIf mv = 2 Then
        OS1.Image = Image.FromFile("football2")
        mv = 3
    ElseIf mv = 3 Then
        OS1.Image = Image.FromFile("football3")
        mv = 4
    ElseIf mv = 4 Then
        OS1.Image = Image.FromFile("football4")
        mv = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Form2

```
Public Dim mv As Integer = 1
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    OS2.Left = OS2.Left + 3
    OS2.Visible = True
    If OS2.Left >= 350 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        OS2.Visible = False
        Form3.mv = Me.mv
        Form3.OS3.Visible = True
        Form3.Timer1.Start()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub animate()
    If mv = 1 Then
        OS2.Image = Image.FromFile("football1")
        mv = 2
    ElseIf mv = 2 Then
        OS2.Image = Image.FromFile("football2")
        mv = 3
    ElseIf mv = 3 Then
        OS2.Image = Image.FromFile("football3")
        mv = 4
    ElseIf mv = 4 Then
        OS2.Image = Image.FromFile("football4")
        mv = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Form3

```
Public Dim mv As Integer = 1
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    OS3.Left = OS3.Left + 3
    OS3.Visible = True
    If OS3.Left >= 350 Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        OS3.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub animate()
    If mv = 1 Then
        OS3.Image = Image.FromFile("football1")
        mv = 2
    ElseIf mv = 2 Then
        OS3.Image = Image.FromFile("football2")
        mv = 3
    ElseIf mv = 3 Then
        OS3.Image = Image.FromFile("football3")
        mv = 4
    ElseIf mv = 4 Then
        OS3.Image = Image.FromFile("football4")
        mv = 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is that timer located Form 1 2 or 3?

Comment: bruh my program is broken now why

Comment: pls help I can't fix it

Comment: You should use the code in Form1, Form2, Form3.
Add the extra section to your original code.
And remember to modify the corresponding Form object.

Comment: Can you help me like on discord I dont understand It still doesnt work when I debug it it errors

Comment: Try my updated code where Form3 code is similar to Form2.

Comment: The form2.mv = Me.mv has an error:   'WindowsApplication1.Form2.mv' is not accessible in this context because it is private.

Comment: Add `Public` before `Dim mv`.
`Public Dim mv As Integer = 1`

Comment: So what is the code for form 3?

Comment: Check the updated answer.It is similar to Form2.

Comment: There's still an error your code still doesn't work it says here that FileNotFoundException was unhandled

Comment: The exception is caused by the inability to find the football picture.
You need to change the `football1` of `Image.FromFile("football1")` to your image path.

Comment: I put the image files in my debug folder so what do i type

Comment: Then just use your image file name link Image.FromFile("football1.jpg")

Comment: I dont know man it still errors its still the same error

Comment: Make sure you place the images in **yourSolution\YourProject\bin\Debug** directory.
And run your project in debug mode.

Comment: I did but it still has that error and the filenames of the balls are the football1.png and on

Comment: Can I show my screen on discord so you will know the problem?

Comment: Can you provide your code and error message so I don't have to guess where your problem is.

Comment: I provided my code on another answer you can see it now and also the error message

Comment: Pls check the code I still don't know how to fix the error

Comment: Can you please help your code is still broken pls

Comment: What is the file 'Debugsoccerball1' ?

Comment: this is my path C:\Users\63921\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ptptpttptptptptpptptpt\ptptpttptptptptpptptpt\bin\Debug
I think its supposed to be C:\Users\63921\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ptptpttptptptptpptptpt\ptptpttptptptptpptptpt\bin\Debug\soccerball1
but I don't know why its like that

Comment: In which line of your code did the error occur?

Comment: I think in the Image.fromfile part

Comment: it still doesnt work it still has the same error

Comment: Find your image files, copy the path from their properties and try again?

Comment: This is what I did but it still has the same error:

If mv = 1 Then
            OS1.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\63921\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ptptpttptptptpptptpt\ptptpttptptptptptpptptpt\bin\Debug\football1.png")
            mv = 2

Comment: Please provide complete error information.

Comment: That is the complete error information its the filenotfound again

Comment: FilenotFoundexceptionnothandled

Comment: C:\Users\63921\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ptptpttptptptptpptptpt\ptptpttptptptptpptptpt\bin\Debugsoccerball1

Comment: Did you use C:\Users\63921\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ptptpttptptptpptptpt\ptptpttptptptpptptpt\bin\Debugsoccerball1 in your code?
Can you provide a screenshot of the code that contains the error and where the error occurs?

Comment: I have screenshots now look at my answer.

Comment: Did you move resource files that were previously included in the project?

Comment: Yes I did remove them

Comment: This prevents your program from finding these resource files.
If you want to delete resource files, go into project settings (double click on "My Projects" in solution explorer) and on the left you will see some tabs. If you go to the "Resources" tab, you can see all the images etc attached to your project, just click on them and then click the "Delete" button at the top to remove them. This will not cause errors.

Comment: can you show a picture how to do that or like post a yt vid and send the link please?

Comment: nevermind I found out how to do it

Comment: Nvm I gave up on this i just had another idea